# Fetching pictures for skybox dynamically in XNA

Tags: xna, directx, xna-4.0

I made cubic skybox in XNA and i want each face of the skybox to run as video player.I tried to load six videos and render each video on the corresponding face,but this way incurs high processing cost to uncompress six videos in parallel.So i tried another way that to convert the videos into frames and load these frames at runtime using background thread,but the there is flickers and the rendering is too slow.
I want to know if there is more efficient way to deal with this problem

Answer (score 0):

Use appropriate video software to pre-render all the faces of your skybox into a single video (tile each skybox face's video within the frame), and then use appropriate UVs on your skybox vertices so that each displays the correct section of the video.

I imagine you might need to do some kind of trickery (the simplest would be some bleed margin) so that compression artifacts don't make the edges look weird.

(And does your skybox really need 6 dynamic sides? Can you get away with just 5 or even just 4?)

Comment: first about using UV map for six face this will affect the quality of each face image.
second i need to render theses faces according to the camera view .For example if the camera see 2 faces for now ,then i don't need to process the other faces ,but i must save the timeline to cope with the video if the camera turned to the other faces.